# Is it possible to serve Apache's default internal pages with charset utf-8?

Tags: apache-2.2, charset

This question is specifically about the charset Apache (2.2 in my case) uses when serving it's default internal pages. For example, [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html) directory listings, not-found [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) pages, 500-Internal Error pages, etc.

The charset Apache is currently using for these built-in pages is iso-8859-1 (see screenshot).

[image]

Here are my relevant Apache settings:

```
# apache2.conf:

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

My OS is Debian 7 and I'm using it's default prefork binary. I was thinking the charsets on these pages might not be changeable. Or maybe there is a compile-time option that affects the default charset?

And in my (Debian-specific) /etc/apache2/envvars, I sourced my default locale:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/envvars
. /etc/default/locale

$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8

$ env | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Modifying the Content-Type header with [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) has no affect on Apache's default internal pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can do this with a combination of `ErrorDocument`, `<Location>` and `ForceType`, as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
<Location /404.html>
  ForceType "text/html; charset=utf-8"
</Location>
```